# Calling a shell script using subprocess doesn't run all the commands in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a Python script which loops through a folder, creating a shell command for each file.

Each command is written to a shell script and this script is then run using subprocess.Popen. (I need to do this because I also need to set up the environment before for the commands to work).

Here is some pseudocode:

```
def create_shell_script(self):
    '''loop through a folder, create a command for each file and write this to a shell script'''
    # command to run
    base_command="run this"

    #list of files
    command_list=[]

    #loop through the files to create a folder
    for file in my_folder:
        command_list.append(base_command+" "+file)

    # open the shell script
    scriptname="shell.sh"
    shellscript = open(scriptname,'w')
    # set the environment using '.' as using bash below to run shell script
    shellscript.write("#!/bin/bash\n. /etc/profile.d/set_environment\n")

    #loop through commands and write to shellscript
    for command in command_list:
        shellscript.write(command+"\n")

    # use subprocess to run the shell script. Use bash to interpret the environment 
    cmd="bash "+scriptname
    proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

When I run this python script only the first 6 commands within the shell script are executed. The error message from the command suggests the command is truncated as it is read by subprocess.

When I run the shell script manually all commands are executed as expected so I know the shell script is correct.

Each command is pretty instantaneous but I can't imagine the speed causing an issue.

I did try running a subprocess command for each file but I ran into difficulties setting the environment and I like the approach of creating a single sh script as it also serves as a log file.

I have read the subprocess docs but haven't spotted anything and google hasn't helped.

Comment: Have you tried closing the shellscript file object after writing to the file and before running it? Otherwise the file might not be written completely when you execute it.

Comment: That fixed it! thank you. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close the `shellscript` file object after writing the commands to it and before running it via `Popen`. Otherwise, the file might not be written completely before you execute it.

The most elegant solution is to use a context manager, which closes the file automatically:

```
with open(scriptname, "w") as f:
    f.write(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Popen` if you don't understand what it does.  It *creates* a process, but it will not necessarily run to completion until you take additional steps.

You are probably looking simply for `subprocess.check_call`.  Also, storing the commands in a file is unnecessary and somewhat fragile.  Just run `subprocess.check_call(['bash', '-c', string_of_commands)` where `string_of_commands` has the commands separated by newlines or semicolons.

If you do want or need to use `Popen`, you will need to call `communicate()` or at least `wait()` on the `Popen` object.

Finally, avoid `shell=True` if you are passing in a list of commands; the purpose of the shell is to parse a string argument, and does nothing (useful) if that has already been done, or isn't necessary.

Here is an attempt at refactoring your script.

```
def create_shell_script(self):
    '''loop through a folder, create a command for each file and write this to a shell script'''

    command_list=['. /etc/profile.d/set_environment']    
    for file in my_folder:
        command_list.append("run this "+file)

    subprocess.check_call(['bash', '-c', ''.join(command_list)],
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If you want `check_call` to catch any error in any individual command, pass in the `-e` option, or include `set -e` before the commands which must not fail (but be aware that many innocent-looking constructs technically produce an error, such as `false` or `grep nomatch file`).

The majority of functions in [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) are simple wrappers which use and manipulate a `Popen` object behind the scenes.  You should only resort to the fundamental `Popen` if none of the other functions are suitable for your scenario.

If you genuinely need both `stderr` and `stdout`, perhaps you do need `Popen`, but then your question needs to describe how exactly your program manipulates the input and output of the shell.